# Retriving the Model state error message

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate

I have the following action method:-

```
 public ActionResult AddServerToRack(AddServerToRack s)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                   // code goes here
                }
            }
            var errorDesc = ModelState.Select(a=>a.Value.Errors.Select(a2=>a2.ErrorMessage)).ToList();
            string desc = "";
            foreach (var i in errorDesc)
            {
                desc = desc + " " + i.ToString();
            }
            return Json(new { IsSuccess = false, description = desc}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

what i am trying to do is to get all the error messages inside the model state and send them as a json object. but currently i fail to get the description of the error message using the foreach at the end of my action method. so can anyone advice , how i can get all the modelstates error message description .?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for you :-

```
foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values) {
string desc = "";
   foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) { 
    desc = desc + " " + error.ErrorMessage.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: i modified you code by using error.ErrorMessage.toString() and it worked, can you edit you answer, so that i can mark it a answered..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a .Net `LINQ Expression` that does the same as the answer from Kartikeya Khosla above.

```
  string desc = ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(modelState => 
                modelState.Errors).Aggregate("", (current, error) => 
                current + " " + error.ErrorMessage.ToString());
```